What is /mnt used for, and how does it differ from /media?
Linux newbie here.
Was reading about the Linux filesystem and came across the directories /mnt and /media. AFAIK, they're both used for mounting, and I heard /media was the "new" one and it was where all hot-swappable devices (e.g USB sticks) go. So, I decided to experiment...
I plugged in my USB stick then executed ls /media and found that Linux had made a directory named after my username! How sweet. So I executed ls /media/foo (with foo being my username) and found my USB stick's name there. 'SanDisk 12.8.0 amd64 n'. No idea what that means.
Out of curiosity, I decided to ls /mnt, but found nothing!
Sooo... what is /mnt used for again?

In short, /media is the standard place for mounting removable devices on Linux. /mnt on the other hand, is mostly used for temporarily mounting file systems on non-removable media.

The FHS is fairly clear that the system administrator can mount whatever they want to it and does not specify any requirements that mounted filesystems are non-removable, only temporary.

Hmm... What are some examples of non-removable media?

@blockchain200 partitions that aren’t already mounted, disk images, etc. As timuzhti says though, /mnt can be used for anything, including removable media, at the administrator’s discretion — so this answer isn’t quite correct. You seem to be relatively new to Stack Exchange, you don’t have to accept an answer straight away; it’s perfectly OK to wait a while to see what other answers may be given.

@blockchain200 Simple examples of non-removable medias would be HDDs, SSDs and CDROMs. Basically, when you need a screwdriver to attach or remove a storage media to your PC, it's highly likely not removable.
